# Mysql get sum of two tables columns grouped

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

I have 3 tables:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I would like to select the difference of the total gain and total spent per user. So my hypothetical table could be:

[image]

I tried this:

```
SELECT g.total - s.total AS quantity, id FROM
(SELECT SUM(quantity) AS total FROM gain GROUP BY user) AS g,
(SELECT SUM(quantity) AS total FROM spent GROUP BY user) AS s, users
```

But it doesn't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Madhur's solution is fine.  An alternative is `union all` and `group by`:

```
select user, sum(gain) as gain, sum(spent) as spent
from ((select user, quantity as gain, 0 as spent
       from gain
      ) union all
      (select user, 0, quantity as spent
       from spent
      )
     ) u
group by user;
```

You can `join` to `user` if you want users that are not in either table or you need additional columns.  However, that `join` may not be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `users` table as base table, to be able to consider all the users, and then `LEFT JOIN` to the sub queries computing the total spent and total gain. This is because some user may not have any entry in either gain or spent table(s). Also, [`Coalesce()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) function handles the `NULL` (in case of no matching row)

```
SELECT 
  u.id AS user, 
  COALESCE(tot_gain, 0) - COALESCE(tot_spent, 0) AS balance 
FROM users AS u 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT user, SUM(quantity) as tot_spent 
           FROM spent 
           GROUP BY user) AS s ON s.user = u.id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT user, SUM(quantity) as tot_gain 
           FROM gain 
           GROUP BY user) AS g ON g.user = u.id
```

Comment: Thank you for reply! It gives me a syntax error at the end of the query...

Comment: @geggiamarti what is the error ? Please give the exact error message.

Comment: but limit is automatically added by phpmyadmin, so I don't know exactly why there is this error

Comment: @geggiamarti it seems you are using PHPMyAdmin. can you try running this in command line MySQL instead.. PHPMyAdmin is probably complaining because of using `user` as one of the column names. It is a Keyword (but not reserved) in MySQL.

Comment: Thank you, but finally I opted for Gordon's answer